# Iteration scope change

Tags: rally

I would like to build a custom app that will show me the scope change in an iteration.
so i would have 3 types of stories: moved, added or split.
the outcome should be all the stories that are\were in this iteration with the type next to it.
I couldn't see anything in the SDK API to help me identify the stories per their type.

How can I accomplish that?
any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to start out by taking a look at the [Release Scope Change Catalog App](http://www.rallydev.com/help/release-scope-change). Source code is [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/appdefinition/ReleaseScopeChangeApp.html). The app parses Artifact Revision Histories to look for Schedule/Unschedule events. While this doesn't include what you're looking for in terms of split stories, it will capture most of what you're looking for. Adapting it to scope to Iterations instead of Releases would be pretty easy.

Worth mentioning is that in the Lookback API (not yet generally available), this kind of app will be much easier to code, because querying for points-in-scope at a particular moment in time will be a matter of one REST query, with no need to parse Revision Histories. If you're one of the pre-release Alpha customers participiating in Lookback - I'd encourage you to explore this route for sure.